# How to set nic priority?

Tags: 11.04, internet, routing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To allocate data usage efficiently with two internet connections](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63109/to-allocate-data-usage-efficiently-with-two-internet-connections)

I have a wifi dongle as well as a very slow POE wired connection going to my Ubuntu box. I want the Wifi to be the primary route to the internet, but I also want the POE to be plugged in as well, for ssh purposes in case something with the wifi isnt working.

But Ubuntu evidently thinks that since the POE is a wired connection, it should be primary, at least this is what i gather from my slow downloads. How to set the priority?

This is a Natty box.

Comment: It's a routing question. See my answer to [http://askubuntu.com/questions/63109/to-allocate-data-usage-efficiently-with-two-internet-connections/64344#6][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63109/to-allocate-data-usage-efficiently-with-two-internet-connections/64344#6

Comment: Do you still need some help with this?